# HTML page is shown with broken UI [extent report HTML] generated using python+selenium unittest

Tags: python, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

HTML page is shown with broken UI While accessing internal(eclipse)/external(chrome/firefox etc) browser the extent report HTML.
Screenshot of the report when I open the html report[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GNHp.png)

Comment: css files maybe missing or are not loading

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by using http over https for all the libraries. For an example, all these libraries in the html:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600
https://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/e4f8ea1de961161791c01b99a71a1e17f81125cf/cdn/extent.css
https://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/c936a26fc8bb9c5fc0253b5bc6f289e1d14bb595/cdn/extent.js

can be changed to:
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600
http://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/e4f8ea1de961161791c01b99a71a1e17f81125cf/cdn/extent.css
http://cdn.rawgit.com/anshooarora/extentreports/c936a26fc8bb9c5fc0253b5bc6f289e1d14bb595/cdn/extent.js

and also:

This small change solves my problem.
Thanks For help.

Comment: Changing  https to http should not be a reliable solution.